# Mocking a React Native component method and testing whether it's called (Jest/Enzyme)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, automated-tests, jestjs, enzyme

So I'm trying to test whether or not a React Native component method calls another method.

```
const render = shallow(<Login navigator={mock Navigator} />);
const instance = render.instance();
instance.fetchAuthToken = jest.fn();
render.update();
// Call the handleFBAuth function (triggered by user clicking FB button)
instance.handleFBAuth();

expect(instance.fetchAuthToken).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

`handleFbAuth` calls the component method called `fetchAuthToken` which i'm mocking here with a Jest spy. I can verify that the `jest.fn` mock function is indeed being called by e.g. putting a console log in its implementation, but the `expect` statement always returns `false` regardless.

I'm probably not understanding something here. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

handleFBAuth has (mocked) async actions, so I had to use a 0 millisecond setTimeout for them to resolve.